# Avoid running a job for a PR in Github Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a github actions workflow, which lints, builds, tests, releases and deploys the software: common CI/CD steps.

This being a FLOSS project, I want to run some jobs for pull-requests and some only when stuff is pushed to main (master) branch and/or tagged. The latter jobs release and deploy the software, so I want to avoid running those when someone makes a PR *at all costs*.

For the sake of this question details are omitted and all steps abstracted away in shell scripts. The workflow looks like this:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always
  TAG_FILE: "./job_tags.txt"

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Lint
      run: lint.sh

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Build
      run: build.sh

  test:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Test
      run: test.sh

  deploy:
    needs: [lint, test, build]
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags')

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Deploy
      run: deploy.sh
```

There are dependencies (`needs:`) and one if, witch tries to achieve the following:

- For all pull_requests to main, run lint, build, test. **but not deploy**
- For all tagged commits to main, run lint, build, test and deploy.

The things I cannot find in the documentation are:

- What if someone branches off, creates commits, tags them and then makes a PR. Will that trigger the tags? Do I need extra protection in place to ensure the tag was made *on main, of the repo that I hold, and not a fork*?
- How can I match this on tags with a pattern only? Say `v*`, only?

Is this feasible in one workflow file? Or should I split the "run for all PRs" and "run only for tagged commits to main" into separate workflows (I'd rather avoid this as it comes with either a lot of complexity -building own reusable actions- or duplication; since I cannot make a job `needs:` jobs from other workflows).
Is there a function or expression that I'm overlooking which does exactly what I want: filter if this is "my" repo or someone elses in a PR?

Comment: If your project is public on GitHub, only members with write access can push tags. Everybody else can only contribute by creating a fork and create a PR once they want to integrate your changes. What they do in their fork has nothing to do with your repository (e.g. create tags). While you can [create protected branches](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-tag-protection-rules) these are not meant to "protect" you from outside contributors but other members of the project.

Comment: @rethab: thanks. This is how I suspected it to be, but official docs (that I found on this) weren't very clear.